# Clone branch from other remote repository so I can overwrite on my own repo

Tags: git, git-remote

I want to keep two different separate repos, Repo A and Repo B. RepoB must inherit the master branch from RepoA and work on top of it.

RepoB copy of RepoA-master must be keep in sync with RepoA's master. Manually or by any other means.

How can I achieve this? I tried forking but I don't know how to do it right.

Comment: I need to keep separate repos for the sake of simplicity but also because of other limitations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first fork the RepoA and then you will get the working copy of RepoA in your Github account then you can run below command or manually downalod.

```
git clone https://github.com/you-username/your-project.git
```

To keep RepoB upto date with RepoA follow below steps:

```
cd into/cloned/repoB 
git remote add upstream git://github.com/ORIGINAL-DEV-USERNAME/REPO-YOU-FORKED-FROM.git 
git fetch upstream
```

Comment: Thank you but how would I keep RepoB copy of RepoA-master in sync with the original Repo A master?

Comment: Okay here is what you need to do.
```
cd into/cloned/repoB
git remote add upstream git://github.com/ORIGINAL-DEV-USERNAME/REPO-YOU-FORKED-FROM.git
git fetch upstream
```

Comment: @Zurupupz I have updated my answer for proper indentation.

Comment: [doc](https://stefanbauer.me/articles/how-to-keep-your-git-fork-up-to-date)

Here is a full detail documentation.

Comment: Hi, this works though I have a problem when merging because of untracked files in RepoB. I guess I should make a new question for this